# Yocto nativesdk-ncurses fails to build because of include paths not prefixed with sysroot

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-compiling, yocto

I'm trying to build an SDK for the Yocto "dizzy" branch for the imx6qsabresd board.
I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform/blob/jethro/README.adoc, the only difference is that I used the dizzy branch instead of jethro.

Running `bitbake meta-toolchain` now gives me the following error:

```
| echo | gawk -f /mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-ncurses/5.9-r15.1/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/base/MKunctrl.awk bigstrings=1 >unctrl.c
| x86_64-pokysdk-linux-gcc  --sysroot=/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-ncurses/5.9-r15.1/ncurses-5.9/ncurses -isystem/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -I. -I../include -I/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-ncurses/5.9-r15.1/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/../include -I/opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include -isystem/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe  --param max-inline-insns-single=1200 -fPIC -DUSE_TERMLIB -c /mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-ncurses/5.9-r15.1/ncurses-5.9/ncurses/tinfo/access.c -o ../obj_s/access.o
| cc1: error: /opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include: Permission denied
[..]
ERROR: Task 1368 (virtual:nativesdk:/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses_5.9.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

The relevant arguments from above are:

- `-I/opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include`
- `--sysroot=/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux`

ncurses is one of the first packages getting built, I guess the problem is not specific to ncurses.

Apparently the compiler tries to access the absolute include dir `/opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include`, without considering the sysroot prefix `/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux`. Both together, `/mnt/space1/yocto-dizzy-imx6/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/opt/poky/1.7.3/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include`, would be the correct include path.

Now, who is at fault here? The compiler for not considering the `--sysroot` argument when looking at the `-I` include dirs? Or is there a mistake in the Yocto recipes somewhere? Maybe it was Yocto's job to prefix the include path? Any other hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to apply this [patch](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses.inc?h=jethro&id=47f67fae98faec17087a827eff141e05b0400560). Specifically, these lines

`#Remove ${includedir} from CPPFLAGS, need for cross compile`

`sed -i 's#-I${cf_includedir}##g' ${S}/configure || die "sed CPPFLAGS"`

```
 if [ -d "${D}${includedir}/ncurses" ]; then
        for f in `find ${D}${includedir}/ncurses -name "*.h"`
        do
        f=`basename $f`
        test -e ${D}${includedir}/$f && continue
            ln -sf ncurses/$f ${D}${includedir}/$f
        done
    fi
```

---

```
diff --git a/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses.inc b/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses.inc
index 10f7dd1..225e369 100644
--- a/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses.inc
+++ b/meta/recipes-core/ncurses/ncurses.inc
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ BINCONFIG = "${bindir}/ncurses-config"
 inherit autotools binconfig-disabled multilib_header

 # Upstream has useful patches at times at ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses/
-SRC_URI = "${GNU_MIRROR}/ncurses/ncurses-${PV}.tar.gz"
+SRC_URI = "ftp://invisible-island.net/${BPN}/current/${BP}-${REVISION}.tgz"

 EXTRA_AUTORECONF = "-I m4"
 CONFIG_SITE =+ "${WORKDIR}/config.cache"
@@ -97,6 +97,8 @@ do_configure() {
         # broken because it requires stdin to be pollable (which is
         # not the case for /dev/null redirections)
         export cf_cv_working_poll=yes
+   #Remove ${includedir} from CPPFLAGS, need for cross compile
+   sed -i 's#-I${cf_includedir}##g' ${S}/configure || die "sed CPPFLAGS"

    # The --enable-pc-files requires PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR existed
    mkdir -p ${PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR}
@@ -105,6 +107,7 @@ do_configure() {
        return 1
    ! ${ENABLE_WIDEC} || \
        ncurses_configure "widec" "--enable-widec" "--without-progs"
+
 }

 do_compile() {
@@ -231,7 +234,14 @@ do_install() {
             # At some point we can rely on coreutils 8.16 which has ln -r.
             lnr ${D}${base_libdir}/libtinfo.so.5 ${D}${libdir}/libtinfo.so
         fi
-
+        if [ -d "${D}${includedir}/ncurses" ]; then
+            for f in `find ${D}${includedir}/ncurses -name "*.h"`
+            do
+           f=`basename $f`
+           test -e ${D}${includedir}/$f && continue
+                ln -sf ncurses/$f ${D}${includedir}/$f
+            done
+        fi
         oe_multilib_header curses.h
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! While the patch didn't apply for my Yocto version, it pointed me to the source of the problem, and I managed to fix it in a very similar way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from LightenS lead me to the right place to look.
Here's some more details:

ncurses' `configure.in` contains a call to the `CF_INCLUDE_DIRS` macro, which is defined in `aclocal.m4`. That macro adds an include path without prefixing it with the sysroot, which breaks the build.

Normally the fix would be changing the macro in `aclocal.m4`, but that is not possible because "ncurses requires a patched autoconf213 to generate the configure script. This autoconf is not available". So instead `configure` needs to be patched.

For reference, this is the patch I created for Yocto dizzy:

```
Index: ncurses-5.9/configure
===================================================================
--- ncurses-5.9.orig/configure
+++ ncurses-5.9/configure
@@ -18601,10 +18601,10 @@ if test "$GCC" != yes; then
 elif test "$includedir" != "/usr/include"; then
        if test "$includedir" = '${prefix}/include' ; then
                if test $prefix != /usr ; then
-           CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I\${includedir}"
+           :
                fi
        else
-       CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I\${includedir}"
+       :
        fi
 fi
```